# passing pointers between functions

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have some problem when I pass a variable between two functions.

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct line{
    char *station;
    int *time;
    struct line *next;
} *Line;
```

And then the first function:

```
void readFile(FILE *network, Line *list){
int line;
char station[40];
char next[40];
int time;

char buffer[128];

while(fgets(buffer, 128, network)){
Line newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct line));
sscanf(buffer, "%d, %50[0-9a-zA-Z ], %50[0-9a-zA-Z ], %d", &line, station, next, &time);

newNode->station = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
strcpy(newNode->station, station);
newNode->time = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
newNode->time = &time;
newNode->next = *list;
*list = newNode;

printf("%s %d\n",newNode->station, *newNode->time); // This one print each newNode->time correctly...
  }
}
```

Second function:

```
void print(Line cursor){
  while(cursor != NULL){
    printf("Station: %s ",cursor->station);
    printf("Tid: %d\n",*cursor->time);
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }
}
```

The problem is that in print(), the station-variable is looping out right, but not the time-variable. I can't figure out why...

Here is my function calls also:

```
int main(){

  FILE *network = fopen("network.txt", "r"); // Open file for reading
  Line list = NULL;

  readFile(network,&list);

  printf("%s %d\n",list->next->next->next->station, *list->next->next->next->time);

  print(list);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the first function.
This code:

```
newNode->time = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
newNode->time = &time;
newNode->next = *list;
```

First "newNode->time" is a pointer to int, so it doesn't make sense to allocate space for a string and assign that to time.

Next, you are assigning a pointer to the local variable "time" to newNode->time.
This causes you to leak the just allocated buffer space because you no longer have a pointer to it.
You could do this:

```
newNode->time = malloc(sizeof(int));
*newNode->time = time;
newNode->next = *list;
```

Which should make the code work, but I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.
Probably better to change Line::time to be just "int time" instead of "int *time", then you don't need to make a separate allocation for it.

Also, instead of malloc/strcpy,just use strdup().

Comment: I am trying to construct a linked-list from each row in the text file network, and then construct a function to print it out. I am feeling lost in all this pointer/no pointer decisions...

Comment: It is hard to generalize, but pointers are often needed when you work with variable sized data (like strings), or a variable number of records (like in a linked list). In "line", you could change station to be "char station[40]" since you already have a fixed size limit in readFile(). "line::time" probably should be simply "int time".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
printf("%s %d\n",list->next->next->next->station, ((*list).next)->next->next->time);
```

I may have put some extra parenthesis as i am n0t sure about the precedence right now.